# display up/down arrows or symbols beside RSI or MFI value while rising or falling

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I coded this and it's working great providing me what I need to see MFI and RSI values but I still need to detriment if the vale is rising or falling by using a Unicode characters and symbols or up/down arrows beside each value, I really tried hard to achieve that but I failed so if anyone can help I will be so thankful.. thank you in advance

```
//MFI*******RSI**********
mif = ta.mfi(close,14)
ris1 = ta.rising(mif,14)
fal1 = ta.falling(mif,14)
//**********RSI**********
rsi = ta.rsi(close,14)
ris2 = ta.rising(rsi,14)
fal2 = ta.falling(rsi,14)
//Table************
co1 = (mif > 50)? color.rgb(0, 118, 4) : (mif > 20)  ? color.rgb(223, 120, 40) : 
color.rgb(199, 0, 0)
Co2 = (rsi >= 60)? color.rgb(0, 118, 4) : (rsi > 35)? color.rgb(223, 120, 40) :  
color.rgb(199, 0, 0)

var table tbl = table.new(position.middle_right,1, 2,border_width = 2,frame_color = 
color.rgb(7, 7, 7))
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 0, row = 0, text = "MFI" 
    +str.tostring(mif,format.mintick),text_size = size.normal,text_color = 
    color.white,bgcolor = co1)
    table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 0, row = 1, text = "RSI" 
    +str.tostring(rsi,format.mintick),text_size = size.normal,text_color = 
    color.white,bgcolor = Co2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share with you the solution I've been lookin for and I hope it will be helpful for anyone looking for same thing.

so I just needed to add tow short lines before the table code as:

```
dir1 = ris1? "" : ""
dir2 = ris2? "" : ""
table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 0, row = 0, text = "MFI"+str.tostring(mif,format.mintick),text_size = size.normal,text_color = color.white,bgcolor = co1)
table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 0, row = 1, text = "RSI"+str.tostring(rsi,format.mintick),text_size = size.normal,text_color = color.white,bgcolor = Co2)
table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 1, row = 0, text =""+dir1,text_size = size.normal,text_color = color.white,bgcolor = color.rgb(46, 57, 53))
table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 1, row = 1, text =""+dir2,text_size = size.normal,text_color = color.white,bgcolor = color.rgb(46, 57, 53))enter code here
```

thank you

Comment: it is not accurate yet it will always give down arrow as falling not rising just to let you know, I will keep trying

Answer (score 0):

so to catch up with you since I opened this topic I wanted to update my answer so (ta.falling and ta.rising) did not work with me for some reason so instead I had to identify the falling and rising manually I'm not sure how accurate is this way but so far I see it okay with me so the code is:

```
//MFI*******RSI**********
mif = ta.mfi(close,14)
rsi = ta.rsi(close,14)
//Table************
mfipast =  ta.mfi(close,14) > ta.mfi(close[1],14) and 
ta.mfi(close[1],14) > ta.mfi(close[2],14)
rsipast = ta.rsi(close,14) > ta.rsi(close[1],14) and 
ta.rsi(close[1],14) > ta.rsi(close[2],14)

var table tbl = table.new(position.bottom_right,2, 2,border_width = 
1,frame_color = color.rgb(7, 7, 7))
if barstate.isconfirmed

co1 = (mif > 50)? color.rgb(0, 118, 4) : (mif > 20)  ? 
color.rgb(223, 120, 40) : color.rgb(199, 0, 0)
Co2 = (rsi >= 60)? color.rgb(0, 118, 4) : (rsi > 35)? 
color.rgb(223, 120, 40) :  color.rgb(199, 0, 0)

dir1 = mfipast?  "" : ""
dir2 = rsipast?  "" : ""
table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 0, row = 0, text = 
"MFI"+str.tostring(mif,format.mintick),text_size = 
size.normal,text_color = color.white,bgcolor = co1)
table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 0, row = 1, text = 
"RSI"+str.tostring(rsi,format.mintick),text_size = 
size.normal,text_color = color.white,bgcolor = Co2)
table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 1, row = 0,text =dir1,text_size 
= size.normal,bgcolor =color.rgb(16, 24, 46))
table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 1, row = 1,text =dir2,text_size 
= size.normal,bgcolor = color.rgb(16, 24, 46)) 
//RSI**************MFI*******
```